# How to differentiate a record created by a pick applet and by New button in Siebel

Tags: siebel

Currently I have an applet on which user can either create record by New button or it can add records from a pick applet. I want to differentiate between these two type of records like this:

```
If (Record is by New button)
Field: f = 0
If (Record is by pick applet)
Field: f = 1
```

Can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try an extra Pickmap.

On the PickList BusComp, add a calc field with a hardcode value of "1" in the calculation.

On the base BusComp, on the field with the picklist, add one more pickmap , which stamps the value of the new calc field into the field 'f' (in your example above) of the base bc. Then on the field 'f', add a predefault value of '0'.

If the record in the base bc is created via new record, the value '0' will be predefaulted to 'f'. But when the value is picked, the value '1' should be picked onto 'f'.

Turn on audit trail to debug this.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't calculated field for PickList BC is an overhead for all records for PickList BC ?

Comment: Well, since the calc field is not forced active, it should not be calculated for all records in the picklist BC. It only becomes active during the actual pick action, at that point it should be calculated for only that record. But if you mark that field forced active, or map it into the pick applet, yes, it will be an overhead.